# Codeigniter: Redirecting from one view to another without going through controller class

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am making a OAuth request to Google Contact API and want to redirect response to another page.

- Is it possible without going through Controller? (I understand it will be against MVC model)
- If yes then what will be my complete redirect url for another page which is in `View` folder. Because I have to provide it upfront on Google API Console.

Comment: you can use jquery .load() method

Answer (score 0):

What code have you tried? What data will be displayed on the view. If there's no data it will be easy.

Comment: there is the comment function for this kind of answers